# How to install WIFI driver on Dell Latitude E5430 laptop on Kali Linux?

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux

I spend hours to get WiFi on my Kali Linux Virtual Box on Windows 10. But I couldn't succeed. I have wifi on my windows and Kali Linux can access the internet but it shows a wired connection. How can I access the internet with wifi?

Comment: You should do some research before you post here, or you will get nowhere. That being said, if you're trying to play with wireless from a VM, you need a USB wifi adapter, as your Windows host is using the current wireless adapter.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a virtual machine, your guest OS (kali) does not see your physical hardware.  Instead it only sees virtual hardware as defined by your hypervisor (virtualbox).

In terms of network cards, you're default settings in virtual box are to have a single NAT device.  This means there is a virtual network between your guest (virtual machine) and your host (physical machine).  The guest thinks it has a single ethernet device and that represents its connection to the virtual network. Your host acts as the gateway, like your router does for your LAN, and forwards requests across the connection it has to the internet (in your case, it's probably the wifi).

So in summary, your virtual machine shows it's wired because that's the type of device emulated by virtualbox.  The host machine (your laptop) provides the route to the internet with the same default routing it would use itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can have wifi connection on Kali Linux to solve the problem?